# Interfacing SugarCRM with OpenERP

Tags: database, sugarcrm, odoo, interfacing

I am currently working on a project whereby I have to make both openERP and SugarCRM talk to each other.
For example, if I add a new Account in SugarCRM, this account is also created in OpenERP...and if I create a new Customer in OpenERP, a new customer with same values is created in SugarCRM.

I've searched the net and I found a connector which allows this interfacing.

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/sugar2openerp

This connector is not an easy thing to work with...I had to build a module inside SugarCRM for me to input connection details (url, username, password, etc ).

Now, I dont know how to proceed with the connector...the files contained in it mentioned "accounts_cstm"... should I create it or no?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the import_sugarcrm module (http://apps.openerp.com/addon/6970)?

I've never used it, but it is an certified OpenERP module, which means that it is officially supported by OpenERP SA, so you should be able to get support and post feature requests if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

all table names ended with "_cstm" are the upgrade safe portion of the data you create in SugarCRM (_cstm for "custom"). For example if you add a new field to accounts, the original structure doesn't change. SugarCRM creates your new field in this table, and relates to the original accounts table thru id_c field.
I didn't test the module you are mentioning here, but if well constructed there wouldn't be need of creating such table.